# MongoDB Count() vs. Aggregation

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, nosql-aggregation

I've used aggregation in mongo a lot, I know performance benefits on the grouped counts and etc. But, do mongo have any difference in performance on those two ways to count all documents in a collection?:

```
collection.aggregate([
  {
    $match: {}
  },{
    $group: {
      _id: null, 
      count: {$sum: 1}
    }
}]);
```

and

```
collection.find({}).count()
```

**Update**: Second case:
Let's say we have this sample data:

```
{_id: 1, type: 'one', value: true}
{_id: 2, type: 'two', value: false}
{_id: 4, type: 'five', value: false}
```

With `aggregate()`:

```
var _ids = ['id1', 'id2', 'id3'];
var counted = Collections.mail.aggregate([
  {
    '$match': {
      _id: {
        '$in': _ids
      },
      value: false
    }
  }, {
    '$group': {
      _id: "$type",
      count: {
        '$sum': 1
      }
    }
  }
]);
```

With `count()`:

```
var counted = {};
var type = 'two';
for (i = 0, len = _ids.length; i < len; i++) {
  counted[_ids[i]] = Collections.mail.find({
    _id: _ids[i], value: false, type: type
  }).count();
}
```

Comment: Why not just try it and see?

Comment: @JohnnyHK tried, `collection.aggregate()` seems a bit faster, but not sure, speed tests on 100K almost same. I would like to see community experience.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

`.count()` is by far faster. You can see the implementation by calling

```js
// Note the missing parentheses at the end
db.collection.count
```

which returns the length of the cursor. of the default query (if `count()` is called with no query document), which in turn is implemented as returning the length of the `_id_` index, iirc.

An aggregation, however, reads each and every document and processes it. This can only be halfway in the same order of magnitude with `.count()` when doing it over only some 100k of documents (give and take according to your RAM).

Below function was applied to a collection with some 12M entries:

```js
function checkSpeed(col,iterations){

  // Get the collection
  var collectionUnderTest = db[col];

  // The collection we are writing our stats to
  var stats = db[col+'STATS']

  // remove old stats
  stats.remove({})

  // Prevent allocation in loop
  var start = new Date().getTime()
  var duration = new Date().getTime()

  print("Counting with count()")
  for (var i = 1; i <= iterations; i++){
    start = new Date().getTime();
    var result = collectionUnderTest.count()
    duration = new Date().getTime() - start
    stats.insert({"type":"count","pass":i,"duration":duration,"count":result})
  }

  print("Counting with aggregation")
  for(var j = 1; j <= iterations; j++){
    start = new Date().getTime()
    var doc = collectionUnderTest.aggregate([{ $group:{_id: null, count:{ $sum: 1 } } }])
    duration = new Date().getTime() - start
    stats.insert({"type":"aggregation", "pass":j, "duration": duration,"count":doc.count})
  }

  var averages = stats.aggregate([
   {$group:{_id:"$type","average":{"$avg":"$duration"}}} 
  ])

  return averages
}
```

And returned:

```js
{ "_id" : "aggregation", "average" : 43828.8 }
{ "_id" : "count", "average" : 0.6 }
```

The unit is milliseconds.

hth

Comment: Thank you for reply. Could you please give your opinion on my update (second case)?

Comment: @itsme No. First for the lack of basic politeness, and second because I will not support the misuse of MongoDB as an RDBMS.