# Mongodb 3.2 (Aggregation) : Group by multiple values of the same attribute

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework

I have the following count queries :

```
db.collection.count({code : {$in : ['delta', 'beta']}});
db.collection.count({code : 'alpha'});
```

for the given data set

```
[
    {
        "code": "detla",
        "name": "delta1"
    },
    {
        "code": "detla",
        "name": "delta2"
    },
    {
        "code": "detla",
        "name": "delta3"
    },
    {
        "code": "detla",
        "name": "delta4"
    },
    {
        "code": "beta",
        "name": "beta1"
    },
    {
        "code": "beta",
        "name": "beta2"
    },
    {
        "code": "beta",
        "name": "beta3"
    },
    {
        "code": "beta",
        "name": "beta4"
    },
    {
        "code": "beta",
        "name": "beta5"
    },
    {
        "code": "alpha",
        "name": "alpha1"
    },
    {
        "code": "alpha",
        "name": "alpha2"
    },
    {
        "code": "alpha",
        "name": "alpha3"
    }
]
```

Is there any way to achieve this using ***single aggregation()*** and nested $group in **mongodb@3.2**?
I understand that this is a classic usecase for **mapReduce()**, but I am out of option here as the $group by parameters (`code` in the above example), is a dynamically generated attribute, hence the aggregation stages building is also dynamic.

**Expected output** is same as the result of the two count queries. 
-> First count query (delta, beta combined count) -> 9
-> Second count query (alpha count) -> 3

Comment: Could you post the expected output

Comment: @AnthonyWinzlet edited the post. Should be the combined result of the two count queries, 9 and 3 respectively on the given data set.

Comment: Possible dupe of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52088666/multiple-counts-with-single-query-in-mongodb ?

Comment: @AnthonyWinzlet $facet is available in 3.4, not in 3.2. Not a dupe. :)

Comment: Have a look at the second answer it will work

Comment: @AnthonyWinzlet Thank you, trying it out. Will close the question as dupe if that works. Thank you again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use below [**`$group`**](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/group/) [`aggregation`](https://mongoplayground.net/p/EO_ETP2teZc)

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  { "$group": {
    "_id": null,
    "first": {
      "$sum": {
        "$cond": [{ "$in": ["$code", ["detla", "beta"]] }, 1, 0]
      }
    },
    "second": {
      "$sum": {
        "$cond": [{ "$eq": ["alpha", "$code"] }, 1, 0]
      }
    }
  }}
])
```

But I will prefer to go with the two count queries for the better performance

`$in` is also released in version **3.4**. You can either use [**`$setIsSubset`**](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/setIsSubset/) for the prior versions

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  { "$group": {
    "_id": null,
    "first": {
      "$sum": {
        "$cond": [{ "$setIsSubset": [["$code"], ["detla", "beta"]] }, 1, 0]
      }
    },
    "second": {
      "$sum": {
        "$cond": [{ "$eq": ["alpha", "$code"] }, 1, 0]
      }
    }
  }}
])
```

Comment: Thank you again @AnthonyWinzlet. I am equally doubting the implementation of n count vs single aggregate with n $group queries. Would if you great if you can point out some caveats in performance, unable to run executionStats on aggregation via mongo shell. Mongo 3.2 bug.

Comment: This is what you are seeking for https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33181878/mongodb-count-vs-aggregation

Comment: looks like $in(aggregation) is also new in 3.4. Retrying changes with $setIsSubset

Comment: Worked, alternately used $project as well. 
```db.collection.aggregate([ 
     { $project: {
        _id: 0,
        Groups: 1,
        first: {
        "$cond": [{ "$setIsSubset": [["$code"], ["detla", "beta"]] }, 1, 0]},
        second: {
        "$cond": [{ "$eq": ["alpha", "$code"] }, 1, 0]
      }
    }},
    { $group: {
        _id: "$Groups",
        sumfirst:  {$sum: '$first'},
        sumsecond: {$sum: '$second'}
    }}]);
```
Had somewhat a better performance, however ,not better than multiple count queries.